# compound FK table of many to many relationship database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design, data-modeling

I'm building an api, but I'm too afraid to it wrong with db design. I'm trying to practice an address book, where employee can have their addresses (home, work, other). So is this many to many relationship?

Is my db design correct? a compound table is created to for flexibility

[image]

[image]

Is ON DELETE and ON UPDATE important here? How to set it so that an employee is removed, we don't want to keep other records in other 2 tables?

Comment: address_type (FK address_type_id with person_address), person_address (FK person_id with person, CASCADE) - no?

Answer (score 1):

First off I feel compelled to add that SO is not really the place for this, I am not sure but it wouldn't surprise me if there is a site/board just for Databases. A lot of this stuff is personal preference and Opinion.

Probably something like this would be a more appropriate place:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/

That said:

- I would change the PK to just `id` in the tables, so `address_type.id` it would just be id and the same for person. It just becomes to redundant to do person.person_id
- the id's should be `INT(10) unsigned AUTO INCREMENT` 10 is ten places, or about 99,999,999,999. You can't have negative ID's so the DB should enforce this. I do 10 because, it's `INT(11)` and that keeps the sign place reserved. It's not really necessary, but i do it out of habit for any unsigned int.
- I would plural the bridge table `persons_addresses`. Because, records in `person` or `address` are for one entity.  Records in the bridge table are for multiple entities. For me it makes it easier to tell that it's a bridge table. All others are singular these are plural, for example.

The main thing for "naming convention" is to be consistent. if you do `{table}_id` for your IDs then do them all that way.  If you do `person` don't do something like `zipcodes` for a table.  And even the column names if you do `person_id` then dont do any columns like `FullName`, `fullName` or `Full_name` etc. I would say pick a way and stick to it, it makes it much easier when you write code if you know ahead of time the table name will be singular.  As I said I like the plural use for the bridge table as you would seldom use them by themselves.

For the relationship.  You would still have to delete `person` and `address` separately. But the record in `persons_addresses` would be updated or deleted if you changed them to cascade.  I think of it this way: the table that defines the relationship is the one that receives the changes.

This is the way it should be though.  Imagine you have 2 person records with the same address.  If you delete one person, you don't want the address deleted from both of them.  Also, you would probably not want a person deleted if their address was deleted.  So at most it should be:

```
person > persons_addresses > address
```

I am not sure if there is an automatic way to delete the address when there are no records in the bridge table.  I've always just manually done it, but you could use a `trigger` to do it if there is not a better way.

For reference:

> A trigger is a named database object that is associated with a table, and that activates when a particular event occurs for the table.
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html

To be honest I've never done it for that and I think triggers may not fire on cascade actions, I remember something about only being fired on SQL statements.  In which case it may be better to do the delete from `person` solely with the trigger.  So you would delete a person, the trigger would fire and you would check if anyone else uses the address, If `false` you delete both the `persons_addresses` record and the `address` record. If `true` you would only delete the `persons_addresses` record.

---

One other thing I would do, is break address down to have a separate `zipcode`.  At my work we purchased a DB table with all the US zipcodes, which contain all the city, state, county, zip ( of course ) and the latitude and longitude.

By using that our address table contains a Many to One relationship to zipcodes.  One zipcode can have many addresses associated with it.  And we also break that down by state using a state table. So it becomes

```
address
 id | street | street2 | zipcode_id

zipcode
id | city | state_id | county | zip | latitude | longitude

state
 id | name | abbreviation
```

Then when users enter a zipcode it shows an auto-complete with all that information in it.

Then the final thing we do is normalize all the `ST`, `N`, `NW` etc. We chose to change them to the full name so `ST` becomes `STREET` when saved.  We went that way because you could have street addresses like `187 NORTH PARK` which would look like `187 N PARK` which is way worse then `187 PARK NE` becoming `187 PARK NORTH EAST`.  You would be amazed the variation on addresses, what I call the "dirt" or "dirtyness".

All of this, combined, removes a lot of errors.  But as I said in the comments we deal with lawsuit data, so we have to have more accuracy and thus more complexity then just an address book.

Comment: so where to ask this kind of question? DB design is opinionated but I think it's not hard to spot a bad db design.

Comment: That depends, on how it's hard or not. Databases can get quite complicated. Especially if you have circular relationships.  Also a good design is not just the nuts and bolts. It has to model the data correctly. You shouldn't pick the Database Model, the data should.

Comment: For example I did a database for lawsuits.  Now the statutes for lawsuits are like   `15 USC 20` then `15 USC 20 (a)` or `15 USC 20 (b)`, then `15 USC 20 (a)(1)` etc.  Essentially a Tree, so I used a nested set model, which is a real challenge to do, but it was the correct way to do it.  See you cant have  `15 USC 20 (a)(1)` without both  `15 USC 20 (a)` and  `15 USC 20`.  This was actually a re-do of a database, the old one had a single table and a bridge table, so by doing a tree I could save just the end of the branch, and find the rest based on the tree design, thereby reducing records.

Comment: The old one also was full of `holes` where only some of the statutes were picked, like for example they had `15 USC 20` and `15 USC 20 (a)(1)` but not `15 USC 20 (a)` So if you searched for `15 USC 20 (a)` you would not find the lawsuit.  But with the trees it's possible to find the path correctly as long as the last statute was picked.

Comment: _No_, the `10` in `INT(10)` means _nothing_ (unless you also have `ZEROFILL`.  An `INT` is _always_ 32 bits (4 bytes).  `INT SIGNED` has a range of about +/-2 billion; `INT SIGNED` has a range of 0..4 billion.